# If something was unusable/unavailable when I made "early shabbos", does it become muktzeh?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, time, muktzeh

Normally an object is defined as *muktzeh* if, at the time Shabbos started (let's call it "dusk"), it was unusable. If an apple was on the tree at sunset and falls off the tree two hours later, that apple is muktzeh for all of shabbos.

Now suppose I make "early shabbos", and walking home from shul (before sunset), I see an apple fall off the tree. Is that apple now *muktzeh* for me? My neighbor sees the same apple; he's running some errands and won't accept shabbos until around sunset, so the apple is not *muktzeh* for him. Does that create halachic issues if an object is muktzeh for some and not others? (Let's say two spouses accept shabbos at different times, assuming that's okay...)

Comment: מגו דאתצואי לבין השמשות...

Comment: See Mishnah Berurah 308:170

Comment: @שלום thanks, but perhaps it's different when the issue here is one of timing, not the nature of the object itself. It does raise the thorny issue -- if two spouses each earn about the same, generally plan decisions with equal input, and let's say they alternate weeks on who cooks for shabbos, how does a household operate if stuff is muktzeh for one but not the other? Call me a Reconstructionist egalitarian if you like, but I can't really label someone "the baal habayis" over the other in that case.